# How can I link an input to a react router link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a react.js project that needs to have a image button or an input that goes to a react router link but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Here's my code:

```
render: function() {
return (
  <div className="Item" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' +    this.props.poster + ')'}} >
    <div className="overlay">
      <div className="title">{this.props.title}</div>
      <div className="rating">{this.props.score} / 10</div>
      <div className="plot">{this.props.overview}</div>
      <div className="play"><input className="button" type="image" src="www.url.to/the/image"></input></div>
      <Link to={`/${this.props.id}`} id="link"/>
      <ListToggle />
    </div>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Wrap everything inside the `Link`:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <Link to={`/${this.props.id}`} id="link">
            <div className="Item" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' +    this.props.poster + ')'}} >
                <div className="overlay">
                    <div className="title">{this.props.title}</div>
                    <div className="rating">{this.props.score} / 10</div>
                    <div className="plot">{this.props.overview}</div>
                    <div className="play"><input className="button" type="image" src="www.url.to/the/image"></input></div>
                    <ListToggle />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Link>
    );
}
```

Comment: In ReactRouter the Link element is an anchor element and as such, it cannot contain a div element even if browsers don't seem to care, it's incorrect.